# How to replace BASH spinner on subprocess failure

Tags: bash, shell, formatting, subprocess

I'd like to implement a function that will take a subprocess PID and display an animated spinner while the subprocess is 'processing'. In addition, I'd like the 'spinner' to be replaced with a check when the subprocess exits successfully, and a cross when it exits in error. I am able to accomplish the first scenario well. However, when the subprocess fails, the message that the subprocess sends to STDERR is printed on the same line as the spinner, and the cross is printed on the wrong line. See the function, and some sample output below:

```
spin()
{
  local -r msg="${1}"
  local -r pid="${2}"
  local -r delay='0.75'
  local -a marks=('/' '-' '\' '|')

  while kill -0 $pid 2>/dev/null; do
    printf "[%s] $msg" "${marks[i++ % ${#marks[@]}]}"
    sleep "${delay}"
    printf "\r"
  done

  wait $pid
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    printf "[\033[0;32m\xE2\x9C\x93\033[0m] $msg\n"
  else
    printf "[\033[0;31m\xE2\x9C\x97\033[0m] $msg\n"
    exit 1
  fi
}

(sleep 3; echo 'This is stdout') >/dev/null &

spin 'Testing subproccess success' "$!"

(sleep 3; echo 'This is stderr' >&2; exit 1) >/dev/null &

spin 'Testing subprocess failure' "$!"
```

Outputs:

```
[✓] Testing subproccess success
[|] Testing subprocess failureThis is stderr
[✗] Testing subprocess failure
```

As you can see, in the scenario where the subprocess exits in error, the message with the spinner 'pauses' and the STDERR message is printed directly afterwards, then the message intended to replace the spinner is printed on the line after.

I must be misinterpreting the way the while loop works within the function. I would expect the beginning of each iteration to be a 'blank line' thanks to the `printf "\r"` at the end of each loop. I'm not sure why it prints the way it does.

I'd like the spinner to be replaced with the red cross, and the STDERR to be printed on the line afterwards, like so:

```
[✓] Testing subproccess success
[✗] Testing subprocess failure
This is stderr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve by using `\n - is the new line character` as below

`(sleep 3; echo -e '\nThis is stderr' >&2; exit 1) >/dev/null &`

Comment: That was just an example to show how the function behaves. I won't be able to control the STDERR output of any program I don't own the source code for.

Comment: do u want to divert all STDERR to null ?

Comment: No, ideally I wouldn't like to have to redirect STDERR at all, but the solution may well have to involve redirecting it to some temporary file.